# Where do I report a Windows core library problem?

Tags: windows, msdn, bug-reporting, core-api

How do I let Microsoft know about a problem I've found in one of their core library routines? Do they have a central repository to report these things?

I am not a member of Microsoft Development Network (MSDN).

Or should I even bother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why [ChrisN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3853/chrisn) took back his answer. I saw it earlier today when he had it up, He said:

> You can report bugs on the [Microsoft Connect website](http://connect.microsoft.com) (I've done this in the
>   past). You don't have to have an MSDN
>   subscription.

I had not heard of the Microsoft Connect website, but when I used the search box there to search for "Registry Unicode", the first entry listed was a bug very similar to the one I encountered. And [clicking through on that entry](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=343523&wa=wsignin1.0) led me to look at the conversation that appears to be Microsoft people addressing the issue, passing it on to appropriate people and escalating it as necessary.

I have no experience with the Microsoft Connect website, but if it turns out to be as promising as it appears, this may be the answer to my question.

Comment: Connect is "retired" (as your link shows). Replaced by https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/ where only VS core bugs can be reported. Anything else is "Closed - Other Product" for which good luck finding a public tracker.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official way to report bugs to Microsoft for an end-user. If you are participating in a beta program for an upcoming release, the beta program includes a bug-reporting channel. Otherwise, if the bug causes problems that you want to get resolved, you can call Microsoft support, and they will help you solving the problem (be it by providing a patch, or a work-around); if the problem turns out to be caused by a bug indeed, they will refund the costs of the support call.

Microsoft does have a central repository (perhaps separate ones per product), but this repository is not accessible for the general public.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a documentation bug (or if the documentation should call it out), you can get good results with the Feedback links in MSDN library. You can report bugs in Microsoft developer tools (among other things) by signing up at connect.microsoft.com.

If you're sure you've found a bug in a core library routine, you can raise a PSS (support case. It'll cost you money, but if it turns out you're right (and they issue you a hotfix), I think that they refund the money.

I've never been so confident that I've found a bug that I'm willing to make that gamble.

Comment: No you can't. If it's not a VS bug it will get closed as "Closed - Other Product".