# Odd Progress Value Behaviour when SendMessage Color to Progress Bar

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi

I am using SendMessage to change the colour of a progress bar. This works ok but I am seeing some odd behaviour related to the progress bar value.

When the bar is green it works as expected, but when it is red or yellow the bar is one block position out of sync with the progress bar value. The example code below steps down through progress bar values from 4 to 0 with progress bar maximum set to 4.

When the bar is green progress value 4 gives a full bar and all integer steps down to zero behave as expected. But when the bar is red or yellow it shows full bar or no bar for value 4 depending on where it was before. It shows FULL BAR for progress value 3, then steps down 1 block out of sync with the value until finally it shows no blocks when the progress value resets to maximum. If this sounds confusing then I'm with you all the way.

I am an avid trawler of SO and have been for many years and to date my questions have always been answered without the need to specifically ask. But while I can find a lot of progress bar questions I can't find any that relate to this issue and it is seriously confusing me. Am I missing something in my code or is this a bug?

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll"
        (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer,
         ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 4
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum
    End Sub

    'Step down through progress bar values (4 to 0)
    Private Sub Step(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmdStep.Click
        If ProgressBar1.Value > 0 Then
            ProgressBar1.Increment(-1)
        Else 'Progress bar back to Max after reaching zero
            ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum
        End If
        'Show current progress bar value
            TextBox1.Text = ProgressBar1.Value
    End Sub

    'Set colour (1 to 3)
    Private mProgressColour As Integer = 1 'Initial colour: Green
    Private Sub TBox(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
        'Change the progress bar colour according to colour value selected (1 to 3)
        If TextBox2.Text <> "" Then
            mProgressColour = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
            SendMessage(ProgressBar1.Handle, &H410, mProgressColour, 0)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Screen grab showing odd progress bar behaviour]

EDIT: Following advice from Visual Vincent I looked into class declarations and although it didn't fix this problem he gave me some good advice. Because Vincent pointed me to a C# declaration example I rewrote the program in C# and it exhibits exactly the same odd behaviour when changing progress bar colours. I apologise if mixing C# and VB in a question is bad form but in this case I think it's valid as the problem seems to be common to both.

As with the VB version (above) a new project was started, the controls added to the form and the code entered into the form class. No other code, events or background workers to interfere with the program flow.

```c#
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //For [DllImport]
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(){InitializeComponent();}

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProgressBar1.Maximum = 4;
            ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum;
        }

        private void CmdStep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ProgressBar1.Value > 0)
            {
                ProgressBar1.Increment(-1);
            }
            else //Progress bar back to Max after reaching zero
            {
                ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum;
            }
            TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(ProgressBar1.Value); //Show current progress bar value
        }

        private int mProgressColour = 1; //Green
        private void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Change the progress bar colour according to colour selected in TextBox2 (1 to 3)
            if (TextBox2.Text != "")
            {
                mProgressColour = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text); //Convert Text box value to Integer
                IntPtr ipProgColour = (IntPtr)mProgressColour; //Then convert the Integer to IntPtr
                SendMessage(ProgressBar1.Handle, 0x410, ipProgColour, IntPtr.Zero); //Do it!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The screengrab below shows the C# program outputs. I haven't shown the green bar because it behaves normally and I have used the yellow bar this time just to show that this colour bar exhibits the same behaviour as the red coloured bar.

[image: Screengrab showing C# example of progress bar colour issue.]

I have been racking my brain trying to think of causes. It's like the red/yellow coloured bar data bits are rotated. But I assume it's the same object as the green bar, it has the same handle. But maybe it's not and that's just mind-blowing. Any ideas guys? If you get a bit of time can I humbly ask you try running this code by copy pasting it into a new form like the one shown and let me know that I'm not going mad! Thanks.

Comment: This probably won't fix your problem, but your `SendMessage` declaration is incorrect. The one you're using now is for VB6 and is not fully compatible with VB.NET. The correct declaration should be using the [**`DllImport` attribute**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and different parameter types. It can be found here under _**VB.NET Signature**_: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage(2012-06-11-11-00-24.0835--203.99.208.4).html

Comment: A good thing to keep in mind is: Do not use _**any**_ `Declare Function ... Lib` that you find online, as pretty much all of them are for VB6 and thus **not** compatible with VB.NET. It is better to look for the C# declaration and then convert that using an [**online converter**](http://converter.telerik.com/).

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can try to reproduce. I bet there is a bug in the code you _don't_ show.

Comment: Thanks Visual Vincent. It didn't fix the problem but your declarations advice is taken on board for future reference. See my edit above. And zett42 there is no other code involved so you would lose your bet. The code I posted is minimal, complete and verifiable. In fact I spent hours extracting it from the actual program and making a new blank project containing only the extracted code you see above. It's been fully tested and apart from what VS adds to the project the only code missing is the Form Class declaration and End Class, but I thought this was obvious. I'm sorry if it wasn't.

Comment: For what it's worth the link I gave you contains a valid VB.NET declaration as well, if you scroll down to _**VB.NET Signature**_. I didn't say that you need to literally _switch_ to C#, only that if you don't find a VB.NET `DllImport` declaration then if you can take a C# declaration instead and convert that to VB.NET.

Comment: As for C# having the same problem as VB.NET, that is not strange. The problem lies either with the .NET `ProgressBar` wrapper or the native progress bar control, meaning what programming language you're using doesn't matter.

Comment: Pretty nasty bug in the native control, at least in Win10 Anniversary, it appears to be doing some internal buffering to deal with position updates while the bar is being animated.  The only workaround I found is to slam it over the head in CmdStep_Click:   SendMessage(ProgressBar1.Handle, 0x402, (IntPtr)ProgressBar1.Value, IntPtr.Zero);  Remarkably this workaround doesn't do the job in TextBox2_TextChanged() so not so sure this is an ideal one.

Comment: Thanks again Vincent. I am rewriting some old Excel macros in VB6 and only recently switched to VB.NET as an experiment. I didn't take your comment as a directive, I found the VB example ok but you gave me the idea to rewrite the program in C#. I have previous C++ experience so it was no effort really and now that VB.NET has shown me what .NET can do I plan to write new programs in C# anyway. I agree that the progress bar problem is deeper than the language choice but how do these things get reported and fixed? I'll leave this open for now because it is an unresolved issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Hans Passant - Your mention of buffering gave me an idea. My examples are incrementing one (-) step at a time but I wondered what if the values for the progress bar are entered instead of incremented? What I found is that with the green bar the bar changes position as soon as I enter a value into the text box. With red/yellow bars, when I initially enter a number after program start the progress bar doesn't update. Then when I enter the next number the progress bar updates to the value I set previously (yes buffering). But as I mentioned to Vincent, who fixes these things? Thanks Hans.

Comment: The best way to report something to Microsoft is via [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/). Here's (a little) more info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/276125/3740093

Comment: Thanks Vincent. I have sent the report to MS using your links. It was surprisingly easy to do and it seems to have been accepted. What happens next is in the lap of the gods I guess. Hans - I think you nailed it in your comment but Vincent gave what seems to be the only option for this issue so I think his solution should the answer whatever the outcome from MS. Thanks again guys. As I mentioned at the outset, I haven't asked a question here before because with a bit of SO digging I have always managed to find answers. So chat again in another few years! Cheers. Rodent.

Comment: A Solution: See code above. I was going to close this post but I have a bit of an obsession with bugs - They bug me! I was thinking about what Hans said about buffering and I wondered whether this buffer could be flushed through. Whatever I tried nothing worked. Then I tried simply Increment(0) after the value is set.and this does the trick. The green bar doesn't care and the coloured bars flush through. I have checked both stepping and textbox value inputs. I think Vincent still has the correct answer by suggesting reporting it because this is a workaround it doesn't address the issue itself.

Comment: Neat workaround! That should rather be the answer than just saying "Report it to Microsoft", because what you do _actually answers the question_ (workaround or not). Just for testing though: What happens if you instead of `ProgressBar1.Increment(0)` call `ProgressBar1.Update()` or `ProgressBar1.Refresh()`?

Comment: Thanks Vincent. I had previously tried 'Refresh' to no avail. I didn't know about 'Update'. I must have missed that when scanning the progress bar available methods. But I've tried it now and it doesn't work. FYI, I previously also tried sending the value twice. I tried Increment(1) followed immediately by Increment(-1) thinking it might happen so fast no one would notice. But nothing worked. Because the plus/minus Increment didn't work I didn't think Increment(0) was going to work either, but I had to try it. And it worked. Ironically sometimes logic is not the answer to a logical problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be an internal buffering bug as identified by Hans Passant.
The bug was reported to Microsoft as suggested by Visual Vincent.
The workaround is to Increment(0) after ProgressBar.Value statements.
Note that ProgressBar.Refresh and Update do not resolve this issue.
The following subroutine is from the VB code example with the Increment(0) fix added.

```
'Step down through progress bar values (4 to 0)
Private Sub CmdStep_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmdStep.Click
    If ProgressBar1.Value > 0 Then
        ProgressBar1.Value -= 1
    Else 'Progress bar back to Max after reaching zero
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum
    End If
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ProgressBar1.Increment(0) ' Incrementing by zero causes the progress bar to update
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Show current progress bar value
    TextBox1.Text = ProgressBar1.Value
End Sub
```