# WTSSendMessage not returning timeout when only using MB_OK

Tags: winapi, terminal-services

I'm writing a simple system service to switch on and off the remote desktop access of some computers depending on a schedule. This includes notifying, then logging off remote users that would be connected when the system switches to local-only.

To notify the user, I'm using the [`WTSSendMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtssendmessagea) function, which can display a dialog box inside a given session. It also allows specifying a timeout—which is very important in this case so that if nobody acknowledges the message within a given timeout, the service can simply force the logoff.

The problem I'm facing is that `WTSSendMessage` (at least on the latest Windows 10, version 2004, and on Windows Server 2019 version 1809, the two systems on which I tested) doesn't return `IDTIMEOUT` properly when the dialog box only has the OK button:

```
WTSSendMessage(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, SESSION_STOP_TITLE,
  strlen(SESSION_STOP_TITLE), SESSION_STOP_MSG, strlen(SESSION_STOP_MSG), 
  MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION, SESSION_WARNING_TIMEOUT, &resp, TRUE);
```

In this case, the `resp` variable always contains `IDOK`, independently on whether the user clicks OK or the timeout expires. The documentation doesn't say anything about a special case with a single OK button.

If instead of `MB_OK` I use anything else (e.g., `MB_YESNO`), the call properly works and `resp` will contain either `IDYES`, `IDNO`, or `IDTIMEOUT` depending on what happened. I also tried explicitly using the unicode (`WTSSendMessageW`) version of the function just in case, but it doesn't change anything.

Is this a bug within the terminal services API? I didn't find any references to this behaviour anywhere. Would there be a workaround (besides rephrasing the message and using a Yes/No or OK/Cancel boutton couple)?

Comment: "*Is this a bug within the terminal services API?*" - sounds like it.  It is certainly different behavior than what is documented. File a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you have an idea where to file such a bug? I tried looking around on Microsoft's web site, but couldn't really find a place to report bugs in APIs... There's a related answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/276493/1931985) but MS Connect "has been retired"...

Comment: Another answer on the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/276131/65863 "*There is no official way to report bugs to Microsoft for an end-user.*" :-(